# htaccess redirect "/?id=(.*)", but only at the root?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have been unable to get a redirect to work. The behavior I was hoping to have would redirect from:

```
www.mysite.com/?id=12345
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/?other_id=12345
```

The rule I wrote seems to grab any url matching the very end like:

```
www.mysite.com/directory/another/?id=12345
```

I just want this to work at the root level, not all levels.

The rule I currently have is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?id=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/?other_id=%2 [R=301,L]
```

For some reason I had to include the first regex as it was not accepting it without it. Without the first ^(.*&) It kept saying that the site was creating a redirect that would not work and bombing out, which may be a part of my problem.

IS there a better way to write this rule? or is a root level match alone not possible?

Thank you,

Silvertiger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex from `^(.*)$` to `^$``:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?id=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/?other_id=%2 [R=301,L]
```

The `^(.*)$` regex matches any request URI, so `/`, and `/foo` and `/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt` will all match. But the `^$` only matches `/`.